# Calling dictionary variables from a module in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I am working on processing some data that uses a large dictionary to define lots of things (in this case, different wavelengths of light). The parameters in one dictionary are used to define parameters in a separate dictionary later. It's organized a little like this:

```
def testdict(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5):
    foo = np.array([path1,path2,path3,path4,path5])
    DATA = {}
    for j in range(1,6):
        fdata = loadtxt(foo[j-1], comments="#", dtype=str, unpack=False)
        nn = len(fdata)
        DATA['I3721%s'   % j],DATA['I3721E%s'  % j] = np.zeros([nn]),np.zeros([nn])
        DATA['I3727%s'   % j],DATA['I3727E%s'  % j] = np.zeros([nn]),np.zeros([nn])
        DATA['I3734%s'   % j],DATA['I3734E%s'  % j] = np.zeros([nn]),np.zeros([nn])
        DATA['I3750%s'   % j],DATA['I3750E%s'  % j] = np.zeros([nn]),np.zeros([nn])
```

... and so on. Later, `DATA[]` variables get used in another dictionary like this:

```
def params():
    param = {}
    for j in range(1,6):
        param['o2_3727%s' %j], param['o2_3727E%s' %j] = DATA['I3727%s' %j], DATA['I3727E%s' %j]
        param['o3_4959%s' %j], param['o3_4959E%s' %j] = DATA['I4959%s' %j], DATA['I4959E%s' %j]
        param['o3_5007%s' %j], param['o3_5007E%s' %j] = DATA['I5007%s' %j], DATA['I5007E%s' %j]
```

I've tried to import this file and define it in the code like `dictionary = testdict(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5)` and `parameters = params()` but I keep getting `NameError: name 'DATA' is not defined`. I don't think this is the correct way to do this. I would like to move the dictionaries out of my notebooks as they are absolutely massive and since this is code I inherited from someone else. I can't change how this is structured because a team of people all use this code, but it would be okay to tell them to import a separate file instead. My end goal is to be able to call `param['o2_37271]`. I don't have any experience working with dictionaries like this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to finish `def testdict()` with `return DATA`?

Comment: Your functions aren't returning any value, you have to add `return DATA`, then `dictionary = testdict(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5)` will work, same for the other function

Comment: Thank you, I think that solves it!